# Database Schema Mentor and Mentee relationship and it's representation using JPA

Tags: java, jpa, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I'm trying to figure an appropriate database schema for a system I'd like to create for fun.

The system is for users to register for courses and allow those users with mentors to monitor the status of the courses that their mentee has registered. A mentor can be a mentee and a mentee can be a mentor, each mentee has only one mentor and each mentor can have 0 or more mentees.

What I have thought of is to have a user table of all users in the system each with a unique key, then two tables, mentor and mentee, that contain foreign keys mapped to the user table depending if they are a mentor or mentee or both. In the mentee table, another column will be a foreign key for the mentor id and in the mentor table, another column will be a list of mentee ids under that mentor.

Now for JPA, I'm not sure how to create these relationships or even if my current idea of a schema is legitimate. One thing was creating a user entity and have a mentor and mentee entity that subclasses the user entity. I believe JPA will create a separate table for each entity.

I'd appreciate any help in developing the schema and entities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design of your object model will end up being driven by how you end up using the objects in your application; but here is a reasonable start:

I lean against inheritance as a First Response to any design issue; so I would recommend creating two classes, `Mentor` and `Mentee` that each have a `@OneToOne` relationship to `User` and the obvious relationships between themselves. For example:

```
@Entity
public class User {
    @Id
    private int id;

    private String name;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Mentee {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="MENTOR_ID")
    private Mentor mentor;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Mentor {
    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="mentor")
    private Collection<Mentee> mentees;
    ...
}
```

These classes are mapped to three tables that look like this:

```
USER
    ID : INT (primary key)
    NAME : STRING

MENTEE
    ID : INT (primary key)
    USER_ID : INT (foreign key to USER)
    MENTOR_ID : INT (foreign key to MENTOR)

MENTOR
    ID : INT (primary key)
    USER_ID : INT (foreign key to USER)
```

Comment: Do you know what kind of schema is generated if in JPA I had the entities extend the User Entity and only the User entity had an ID?

Comment: I guess it would depend on which JPA implementation you are using (e.g. Hibernate). I am not a big fan of schema (or entity) generation. One of the main strengths of JPA is that it allows you a lot of flexibility on both sides of the mappings; so you can model your objects and relations more appropriately.